# How do I make text bold after the user clicks a button?

Tags: javascript, html, text

I am trying to make a text editor in JavaScript and it has various features like bolding the text and italics and some others. When the user clicks on any one of them, then anything that they have selected will become edited accordingly. Now I am able to get the selected text and even put strong tags before and after the text but when I do it the text doesn't get bold only the tags are seen. How can make the text bold? I sorry but I am unable to provide code since its too much and too messy. Thanks for reading query! Also if you know any JavaScript library which could help me solve this problem then you can suggest me.

```js
document.getElementById("button").addEventListener("click",
  () => {
    let text = document.getElementById("text").innerText
    let selection = window.getSelection();
    let boldText = "<strong>" + selection + "</strong>"
    document.getElementById("text").innerText = text.replace(selection, boldText)
  })
```

```html
<div id="text">
  The dog barks and runs around.
</div>
<button id="button">Make selected text bold</button>
```

I am using inner text instead of inner html in order to reproduce the problem

Comment: Please add any code you have tried in your question. Questions that do not show an attempt with code will likely down voted and/or closed.

Comment: @dalelandry okay I will get some code in a minute sorry its my fault

Comment: @dalelandry done added some code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using `innerText` to replace which is wrong as we want to change html so use `innerHTML`.
Code:

```js
document.getElementById("button").addEventListener("click",
  () => {
    let text = document.getElementById("text").innerText
    let selection = window.getSelection();
    let boldText = "<b>" + selection + "</b>"
    document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = text.replace(selection, boldText) //use innerhtml instead of innertext
  })
```

```html
<div id="text">
  The dog barks and runs around.
</div>
<button id="button">Make selected text bold</button>
```

Comment: i have added that i have used that purposefully to reproduce the problem in my code i am using innerHTML only

Answer (score 0):

Here is some code that I used to change to inputted text on a button click

```
<input type="text" id="sign" value="">
<p style = "font-family: 'Dancing Script', cursive; font-size:50px;" 
id="signOutput"></p>
<button onclick="signFunction()">Output Signature</button>

<script>

function signFunction() {var x = document.getElementById("sign").value;
         document.getElementById("signOutput").innerHTML = x;
         }

</script>
```

Comment: Umm I dont think you got the question correctly the way you're doing the styles is not ideal for a text editor

Comment: Yeah, my code is used for making user input look like cursive. I'm a little confused by your post what exactly do you need to be done.

Comment: Dont worry i think its my fault for making the question complicated. Let me explain you. In html `strong` tags are used to make bold text. Now when the user clicks on the bold button to make his text bold I am taking the selected text and adding these `<strong></strong>`  tags around it to make the text bold. But the problem is that javascript is just adding the strong text and not actually making the text bold. That's what i have to figure out

Answer (score 0):

```
<p id="mypar">Hello</p>
<br>
<button type="button" onclick="changeStyle()">Click Me</button>
<script>
function changeStyle(){
    var element = document.input
    var element = document.getElementById("mypar");
    element.style.fontWeight = "bold";
}
</script>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).